# Raster Statististics for Polygon

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

The latest version 3.6 is installed, but the raster statistics for polygon doesn't work, also the directional statistical for layer doesn't work as well. ANY HELP

I received the following message,

The following layers were not correctly generated.

- D:/Finland/de.shp

You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution,

The problem was the shf. I was using, the last shf. I created has only one field Id, I recreated a new one has three fields Id name and details, and now it works well.